# Changing the colour of a toggle menu with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website using the latest version of bootstrap, I have a menu that when viewed on a mobile device changes to a toggle menu with the 3 little lines the same as a burger menu. I would like to be able to change the color of the lines as my header is white and so are the lines and they cannot be seen. I have google this but have no joy with changing the color.

**Code:**

```css
 .navbar-header, #myNavbar, .container-fluid {
     background: #fff;
    
   }

   .nav.navbar-nav li a{
   color: #66728d;
   font-size: 18px;
   background: transparent;
 }

 .navbar-brand img {
   
  width:176px !important;
  height:110px !important;
  
 }
 
 
.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  background: #8d8166;
}

    .navbar-header, #myNavbar, .container-fluid img {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom:5px; 
     
   }

   .nav.navbar-nav li a {
   color: #66728d;
   background: transparent;
 }

.navbar-toggle {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"> 
        <img src="images/logo.JPG" alt="Los Angeles">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Specials</a></li>
           <li><a href="#section3">Links</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Contact Us</a></li>
          
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the color of the 3 bars in the hamburger toggle button using this CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: When you add this CSS is it coming after the bootstrap.css file?

Comment: yes it is, I linked it right after the bootstrap css

Comment: It's not a best practice, but it's worth trying. Try adding an !important tag after the color... so background-color: #000 !important;

Comment: he use .navbar-inverse so try change .navbar-default to .navbar-inverse or reverse

Comment: Good eye - totally missed that! I just edited to that .navbar-default is just .navbar